# OneToMany bidirectional relationship does not insert a foreign key in the child entity

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following problem. I have a bidirectional OneToMany relationship. When I try to insert a user object, the address is also added, but without a foreign key.

User Model

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 1)
public abstract class User extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_generator", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Address> address;
}
```

Address Model

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "adresses")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "address_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "address_generator", sequenceName = "adresses_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

User Service (

```
@Service
public class UserService{

    @Autowired
    priate UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDTO createUser(UserDTO userDTO) {

        if(userDTO== null) {
            return new UserDTO ();
        }

        if(userDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new OperationNotAllowedException("Method not allowed.");
        }

        User user = DozerHelper.parseObject(userDTO, User.class);

        userRepository.save(user);
        return DozerHelper.parseObject(user, UserDTO.class);
    }
}
```

I tried other alternatives, but without success. How could I solve this? Is it possible to make this relationship?

Comment: I think the service you provided is not related to your question

Comment: You should create a minimal example that highlights your problem, instead of pasting the whole source code related to the issue. Can you summarize the problem in a few lines of code?

Comment: @psuzzi Excuse me! As I am using lombok, dozermapper and others, I thought it was necessary to inform. I edited it, but still kept the annotations.

Comment: Make sure to assign the `User` object to each `Address` before the save operation.

Comment: I already tried to do this`Set<Address> a = new HashSet<>(); for(AddressDTO ad : clientDTO.getAddress()) { a.add(DozerHelper.parseObject(ad, Address.class)); }`, but it still saves the object without assigning the user id.

Comment: What you want to do is `user.getAddress().forEach(a -> a.setUser(user));` before `userRepository.save(user);` since it's the `Address` that's in charge of populating `user_id` column with the id of associated `User`.